# Finding min and max values in different variables of data subsets

Tags: r

This is probably very simple for all of you guru programmers, but I'm new at R and I seek some help. First I'll try to describe my data and then ask a question.
I have 110k obs. of 24 variables:

```
      qseqid    evalue    pident    lenght    .......
    1 LL_206    3e-22     65.7      612
    2 LL_206    5e-22     75.6      485
    3 LL_206    5e-14     80.6      598
    4 LL_300    4e-22     90.5      251
    5 LL_300    4e-22     64.7      589
    6 LL_300    8e-14     89.8      125
    .
    .
    .
```

Now you can see that my data has subsets at qseqid variable. What I'm trying to get from my data is to find min evalue, max pident and max lenght for each subset of qseqid variable.

My results should look like this:

```
      qseqid    evalue    pident    lenght    .......
    1 LL_206    3e-22     65.7      612
    2 LL_300    4e-22     90.5      251
    .
    .
    .
```

I want that results are presented as csv table and in table should also be included all variables.
I tried aggregate method, but I don't know how to tell R to find first min evalue then max pident and so on.
Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your desired output doesn't match description. It's also unclear which rows you want to returns in case the minimum of `evalue` and the maximum of `pident` or `length` are in different rows in the same group.

Comment: I want to return one row for each qseqid. R should find first min evalue (there can be the same for two observations as in LL_300-I have evalue 4e-22 two times), then it checks for pident max value and last for max lenght value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I can think about it, is to create the function which make a subset of all rows that fulfill first requirement, then subset for the second and so on..

```
ComplexSubset <- function(id){
  data.t <- data[data$qseqid %in% id,] # subset the needed qseqid
  data.t <- data.t[data.t$eval %in% min(data.t$eval),]  # subset the ALL min eval
  data.t <- data.t[data.t$pident %in% max(data.t$pident),]  # subset ALL max pident
  data.t <- data.t[data.t$lenght %in% max(data.t$lenght),]  #subset ALL max lenght
#here you can add additional subseting for your remaining colums
  return(data.t) ## save the row ID
}

## And then run for all unique qseqid

data.final <- data[0,]

for(id in unique(data$qseqid)){
  data.final <- rbind(data.final, ComplexSubset(id))
}
```

This should work. 
Hope it helpful

Comment: Nope not working either. I think this must be done by somesort of function. First check for min evalue, then check for max pident value and last check for max lenght value.

Comment: You are correct, I have edited the code. Now it should work for you.

Comment: thank you, thank you! You're my saviour. Your code works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
res <- group_by(your_data_frame, qseqid) %>%
  summarise(evalue = min(evalue), pident = max(pident), 
    length = max(length))
```

You can then save `res` using `write.csv`/`write.csv2`.

Comment: I've checked this one and it gaved min and max values but not the "right" ones. It's hard to explain, because I'm not native english :)  `If I have:  qseqid evalue pident length  LL_1 1e-34 72.44 283  LL_1 2e-24 70.07 284  LL_1 1e-21 72.46 207  LL_1 1e-21 72.46 207  LL_1 1e-21 72.46 207`  Results were:  `LL_1 1e-34 72.46 284`  It should be `LL_1 1e-34 72.44 283`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is not 100% what I want as output. But it's close...

```
qseqid <- c("LL_1", "LL_1", "LL_1", "LL_1", "LL_2", "LL_2", "LL_2", "LL_2")
evalue <- c(1e-34, 1e-34, 1e-34, 1e-25, 2e-85, 2e-85, 3e-85, 1e-80)
pident <- c(90.5, 90.5, 80.8, 90.5, 75.3, 85.6, 75.3, 65.2)
lenght <- c(485, 503, 897, 1052, 689, 4859, 50, 115)
title <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H")
mojadata <- data.frame(qseqid, evalue, pident, lenght, title)
```

Data:

```
   qseqid evalue pident lenght title
1:   LL_1  1e-34   90.5    485     A
2:   LL_1  1e-34   90.5    503     B
3:   LL_1  1e-34   80.8    897     C
4:   LL_1  1e-25   90.5   1052     D
5:   LL_2  2e-85   75.3    689     E
6:   LL_2  2e-85   85.6   4859     F
7:   LL_2  3e-85   75.3     50     G
8:   LL_2  1e-80   65.2    115     H
```

Code:

```
mojadata = data.table (mojadata)
mojadataout<-mojadata[, list(evalue=min(evalue),
       pident=max(pident[evalue == min(evalue)]), 
       lenght=max(lenght[pident==max(pident)&evalue==min(evalue)])), 
       by=list(qseqid)]
```

Output (what I get):

```
   qseqid evalue pident lenght
1:   LL_1  1e-34   90.5    503
2:   LL_2  2e-85   85.6   4859
```

Output (what I want):

```
   qseqid evalue pident lenght title
1:   LL_1  1e-34   90.5    503     B
2:   LL_2  2e-85   85.6   4859     F
```

Now, how do I put in output variable "title"? I hope this time my question is more understandable.